# Found an unexpected Node #text with name = null and with text content =

Tags: java, wsdl, weblogic, cxf

While deploying a service to weblogic I got the following exception despite cxf successfully generating sources:

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Error encountered during prepare phase
of deploying WebService module 'brt-service-1.0.war'. While deploying WebService
module 'brt-service-1.0.war'.  Error encountered while attempting to Load WSDL
Definitions for WSDL: 'zip:C:/devapps/weblogicDomain/servers/myserver/tmp/_WL_us
er/_appsdir_brt-service-1.0_war/l2mgsr/war/WEB-INF/lib/_wl_cls_gen.jar!/brt.wsdl
'.  Found an un expeced Node #text with name = null and with text content =
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WSEEModule.prepare(WSEEModule.java:149)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.AppDeploymentExtensionFactory.prepare(AppDeploym
entExtensionFactory.java:79)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.AppDeploymentExtensionFactory.access$100(AppDepl
oymentExtensionFactory.java:15)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.AppDeploymentExtensionFactory$1.prepare(AppDeplo
ymentExtensionFactory.java:219)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.prepare
(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:23)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlException: Found an un expeced Node #text with
 name = null and with text content =
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlReader.checkDomElement(WsdlReader.java:106)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.internal.WsdlExtensibleImpl.parse(WsdlExtensibleIm
pl.java:114)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.internal.WsdlDefinitionsImpl.parseChild(WsdlDefini
tionsImpl.java:564)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.internal.WsdlExtensibleImpl.parse(WsdlExtensibleIm
pl.java:116)
    at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.internal.WsdlDefinitionsImpl.parse(WsdlDefinitions
Impl.java:501)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proud of how long this took me to find. The simple things are so often the hardest.

```
<wsdl:part name="response" element="beans:changeRequestSubmitRes"/>]
```

That errant typo'd bracket didn't cause a problem for CXF, but Weblogic, at least at 10.3.6, didn't know what to do with it.